# Local OSM Tile Server not rendering

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, rendering, tile-server

I searched this issue in other topics but only found outdated topics with previous versions of Ubuntu.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in my laptop and I'm following the tutorial available at https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/ and was going fine, except for the last step, which is the tile viewing.

I'm opening the "sample_leaflet.html" file inside folder /src/mod_tile/extra/ using Firefox Browser and it doesn't show tiles. It only shows tiles at lv 0 zoom, which is the same tile shown at http://localhost/hot/0/0/0.png repeated side by side.

[image]

My console show the rendering messages, as the tutorial said it would do.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you go to e.g. http://localhost/hot/1/0/0.png in your browser (i.e. not with the Leaflet client - just a direct request)? This will help determine whether this is an issue with your web application, or if it's some server-side issue.

Comment: "Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80"

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not with your client, but your tile server. So you can ignore `sample_leaflet.html` and take a few steps back to make sure the backend is doing what you expect it to be doing. Unfortunately it's difficult to offer more help since we don't know exactly which part of the tutorial you're following you might not have done correctly. (If indeed the tutorial even works as advertised.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a permission issue, but I don't know exactly what solved it, because I did 2 things.

1) I did the chown command with : after the username, like this sudo chown renderaccount: /var/lib/mod_tile/ but I don't know if the : is needed (the switch2osm tutorial dont use it)

2) I did chown and chmod commands both in /var/lib/mod_tile/ and /var/lib/mod_tile/ajt/ but I'm not sure if an user having permision to write in a folder is enough to write in its subfolder.